# Prime Number Theorem in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, analytic-number-theory

What is the probability that a randomly chosen monic polynomial of large degree $n$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$ is irreducible? We can interpret this probability as $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{N_p(n)}{p^n},$ where $$N_p(n)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{d|n}p^d\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)$$ is the number of monic irreducibles of degree $n$ in $\mathbb{F}_p[x]$. I'm having trouble seeing how one would go about evaluating/describing the asymptotic behavior of this limit, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know about zeta functions?

Comment: Yes I'm reasonably familiar with basic applications of zeta functions.

Comment: @BrunoJoyal I know it has been a while, but may I ask how you would apply zeta functions here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The limit will be zero due to the factor of $\frac{1}{n}.$  Notice that $$\sum_{d|n} p^n\mu\left(\frac{n}{d}\right)=p^n+O\left(np^{n/2}\right),$$ since there are at most $n$ additional terms, each of which is at most $p^{n/2}$ in size.  Thus $$\frac{nN_p(n)}{p^{n}}=1+O\left(n^2p^{-n/2}\right),$$ which implies that

$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{nN_p(n)}{p^{n}}=1.$$

This is the version of the prime number theorem for finite fields, and as you can see, it is significantly easier to prove than the PNT for the integers.

**Alternate proof that $N_p(n)/p^n\rightarrow 0$:** 
As $|\mu(d)|\leq 1$, we have the crude upper bound $$N_p(n)\leq \frac{1}{n}\left(1+p+p^2+\cdots +p^n\right)\leq \frac{1}{n}\cdot \left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^{-1}p^n.$$ From this it follows that $$\frac{N_p(n)}{p^n}\leq \frac{1}{n}\left(1-\frac{1}{p}\right)^{-1},$$ and so the limit is $0$.